# uninitialized local variable 'r' used

Tags: c++, initialization

Find the volume of sphere

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <cmath>
    #define PI 3.1416 
    using namespace std; 

   void sphere(double,double);
   void main()
   { 
   double r ;
   double vol = (4.0/3.0)* PI * pow(r,3); 

   cout<<"\n\n Enter the radius : "; 

   cin>>r; 

   sphere(r, vol);

   cout<<"\n\n The volume sphere is : "<<vol; 

   } 

   void sphere(double r, double vol)
   {
vol = (4.0/3.0)* PI * pow(r,3); 
    }
```

how do i fixed this? it say:
warning C4700: uninitialized local variable 'r' used

Comment: `double r = some value;` or perhaps move `cin>>r;` before you use `r`.

Answer (score 2):

```
 double vol = (4.0/3.0)* PI * pow(r,3);
```

You have used `r`, but what is its value. `double r ;` `r` will simply have garbage value here.

Answer (score 1):

I think "double vol = (4.0/3.0)* PI * pow(r,3); " should be put after "cin>>r". However, as you've used sphere, you might delete this sentence.